# Comparar domínio do formulário com domínio do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso comparar domínio enviado e tratado por um formulário através de `$_POST` com domínios do banco de dados pois só posso inserir um e-mail de cada domínio no banco. Para isso primeiro eu peguei o e-mail do `$_POST` e depois armazenei todos os e-mails da base num array com `mysql_fetch_array` no banco. Agora, preciso fazer com que este `array` retorne só os domínios como fiz com explode que resultou na variável `$tmpdominio` e depois compare estas duas informações para ver se o domínio já existe no banco. Como estou iniciando, até agora tenho esse código.

```
# Pegando o dominio deste email
$emaildoform    = $_POST['email'];
$tmpdominio     = explode('@', $emaildoform);

# Pegando todos os emails da minha tabela
$dados      = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM wp_agencias");

while($arraydeemails = mysql_fetch_array($dados)){

    # Eu preciso extrair o domínio de cada e-mail do array ...
    # ... depois vou comparar com $tmpdominio para ...
    # ...verificar se dominio está presente na base

};
```

Comment: Você já tentou definir o campo email como único no banco? você só pode ter um email com o mesmo domínio no seu banco?

Comment: Já esperimentou usar o [**in_array()**](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)

Comment: No lugar de trazer todos os dados do banco, porque não utiliza o like na sua query para procurar e-mail com o tal domínio? Se retornar algum resultado, é porque o e-mail existe no banco de dados.

Comment: @Filipe é que noutra resposta desses dias atrás, "ensinaram" ele a usar essa coisa de armazenar db em array desnecessariamente. O que é gasto à toa de memória, pois mesmo naquela outra, poderia-se usar o "save result" do MySQL se precisasse manter os dados. O mais engraçado na outra questão é que o dono da resposta complicada disse erroneamente que as outras estavam erradas, e ainda levou o accept :)

Comment: @Bacco pois, a query deve retornar o menor resultado possível e utilizar array nem sempre é a melhor solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez a solução atenda a sua necessidade, aí você terá uma boa ideia do que pode ser feito. Sucesso!

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
   // Recuperando domínio do e-mail recebido pelo form
   $dominio = explode( '@', $_POST['email'] );

   // Pegando todos os emails da minha tabela
   $dados = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM wp_agencias WHERE email LIKE @".$dominio[1]);

if( $dados) {
   echo "Domínio ". $dominio[1]." já cadastrado";
} else {
   echo "Domínio ". $dominio[1]." não cadastrado";
}
}
```

Comment: Muito bom seu código !!! Obrigado.

Comment: Não utilize conteúdos originários de um formulário diretamente em uma consulta SQL. Utilize mysql_real_escape_string() ou prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Extrai apenas o dominio do e-mail.
$dominio = explode('@', $_POST['email']);
$dominio = $dominio[1];

// Torna a string segura para uso em consultas.
// (Evita SQLInjection).
$dominio = mysql_real_escape_string($dominio);

// Consulta se o dominio já existe.
$dados = mysql_query('SELECT email FROM wp_agencias WHERE email LIKE "%@'.$dominio.'"');

if (mysql_num_rows($dados)>0) die("Dominio já existe");
else
{
    // Torna a string segura para uso em consultas.
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    // Insere no banco de dados.
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO wp_agencias(email) VALUES ("'.$email .'");');
}
```

Comment: Muito bom seu código !!!

Comment: Havia um pequeno erro, acabei de corrigir.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro gostaria de saber se essa lista de e-mails é muito grande. Se for ela pode te dar problema de performance. Mas vou falar de duas opções.
Se a tua lista for pequena esse gist aqui pode te ajudar a resolver:

```
<?php
class DomainCheck {
    private $email;

    function __construct($email_a_verificar) {
        $this->email = $email_a_verificar;
    }

    private function getDominio($email) {
        $email = explode('@',$email);
        return $email[ count( $email ) - 1 ];
    }

    function check($lista_de_emails) {
        $dominio_a_verificar = $this->getDominio( $this->email );

        foreach( $lista_de_emails['email'] as $email ) {
            $dominio_atual = $this->getDominio( $email );

            if ( $dominio_a_verificar == $dominio_atual ) {
                throw new Exception("Domínio existente na lista", 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

//a lista simula o seu recordset
//usando um fetchAll do PDO
$lista_emails_do_banco = array(
    'email'=>array(
        'evaldobarbosa@gmail.com',
        'evaldobarbosa@yahoo.com',
        'evaldobarbosa@facebook.com',
        'evaldobarbosa@linkedin.com',
        'evaldobarbosa@phpmaranhao.com.br'
    )
);

$email_recebido_do_form = 'usuario@gmail.com';

$check = new DomainCheck($email_recebido_do_form);
try {
    $check->check( $lista_emails_do_banco );
    echo "Sem duplicações de e-mail";
    //Rotina de salvamento do registro pode vir aqui
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

https://gist.github.com/evaldobarbosa/c302b2d1c327a0708735

Mas se a tua lista for muuuuuuuito grande, então você pode adicionar um campo para o domínio na tabela com os e-mails e então fazer a busca pelo campo domínio.

Comment: Prefira adicionar o código na própria pergunta em vez de usar um sistema externo. Assim podemos manter o código sempre disponível aqui e a resposta continua válida.